# Laravel saying Missing required parameters while giving action in form

Tags: laravel

I have a route like

```
Route::post('admin/newsupdatedata/{id}','NewsController@update')->name('newsupdate');
```

I am giving action in a form for this route like

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('galleryupdate' ,$data['id'])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I am getting id data but it's still giving me parameter missing

Comment: As i know you dont need to use URL:: here just route is fine

Comment: Not sure where the `galleryupdate` is coming from.

Comment: Try using `{{route('newsupdate', $data['id'])}}` in your form action.

Comment: @SatendraRawat It's working thank you

Comment: Glad to help you @MamtaJain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding it as an answer. It may help others as well.

#### Problems

1. No need to use facade `URL`.
2. In the above question, the route name is not matching with what you are using while calling the route.

#### Solution

Try using the following in your form action.

```
{{route('newsupdate', $data['id'])}}
```

#### Solved answer:

```
<form action="{{route('newsupdate', $data['id'])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

You use another route name. You define route with name "newsupdate", but use route "galleryupdate".

Instead facade URL in you form, better use helper route()

```
<form action="{{ route('newsupdate', $data['id']) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```